# Running cli 'at' command via PHP permissions issues

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-4, centos7, at-command

**I.- Preface**

I have a script that runs the following line of code when executed:

```
exec("echo 'cd /usr/share/nginx/myproject && /opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/bin/php artisan run:task mailer' | /usr/bin/at now +1 minute");
```

It successfully schedules a task via the `at` command. I use the following command to verify it worked:

```
[root@acool2 ~]# 
[root@acool2 ~]# atq
19  Thu Apr  4 13:17:00 2019 a nginx
[root@acool2 ~]#
```

We can see the following, from left to right: *job number*, *date*, *hour*, *year*, *queue*, and *username*.

**II.- The Problem**

When the scheduled time is met the command runs but fails. The following information is written in /var/spool/mail/nginx :

```
[root@acool2 ~]# tail -f /var/spool/mail/nginx 
Received: by acool2.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 993)
    id 0E9CF30EBA39; Thu,  4 Apr 2019 13:17:01 -0700 (PDT)
Subject: Output from your job       19
To: nginx@acool2.localdomain
Message-Id: <20190404201701.0E9CF30EBA39@acool2.localdomain>
Date: Thu,  4 Apr 2019 13:17:00 -0700 (PDT)
From: nginx@acool2.localdomain (Nginx web server)

This account is currently not available
```

This is clearly a permissions problem. See *Final Solution*.

**III.- Possible Solution**

Edit sudoers file and add the following:

```
nginx ALL=(acool) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/at
```

Then use the following command in PHP.

```
exec("sudo -u acool echo 'cd /usr/share/nginx/myproject && /opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/bin/php artisan run:task mailer' | /usr/bin/at now +1 minute");
```

See *Final Solution*.

**IV.- The Failure**

After editing the sudoer file and adjusting the PHP code I still have no success. *The Problem* is still happening.

**V.- HELP**

Your help and suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE I**

Some progress to report. The following scheduled the task for *acool*, but...

```
exec("echo 'cd /usr/share/nginx/myproject && /opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/bin/php artisan run:task mailer' | sudo -u acool /usr/bin/at now +1 minute")

[acool@acool2 myproject]$ atq
43  Thu Apr  4 15:02:00 2019 a acool
[acool@acool2 myproject]$
```

... *The Problem* is now with *acool* /var/spool/mail/acool :

```
[acool@acool2 ~]$ tail -f /var/spool/mail/acool 
Received: by acool2.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 1001)
    id 756B830EBA39; Thu,  4 Apr 2019 14:56:00 -0700 (PDT)
Subject: Output from your job       42
To: acool@acool2.localdomain
Message-Id: <20190404215600.756B830EBA39@acool2.localdomain>
Date: Thu,  4 Apr 2019 14:56:00 -0700 (PDT)
From: acool@acool2.localdomain

This account is currently not available.
```

**UPDATE II**

Got it working with Barmar suggestion, adding the `-E` flag to `sudo` and the following change to sudoers file:

```
nginx   ALL=(acool)     NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Which is too liberal IMO.

**UPDATE III - Final Solution!**

*The Problem* is the result of the `SHELL` environment variable being absent/missing. No need to edit the sudoers file or using `sudo` at all. Adding `export SHELL=\"/bin/bash\";` to the original command does the trick. The following is the working solution:

```
exec("export SHELL=\"/bin/bash\"; echo 'cd /usr/share/nginx/myproject && /opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/bin/php artisan run:task mailer' | /usr/bin/at now +1 minute");
```

Good luck! Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the `echo` command with `sudo`, and it's piping to an ordinary `at` command. You need to run the `at` command with `sudo` instead.

```
exec("echo 'cd /usr/share/nginx/myproject && /opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/bin/php artisan run:task mailer' | sudo -u acool /usr/bin/at now +1 minute")
```